# Calculating the force acting between to magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

I am using neodymium N52 magnets in a project I'm working on, and I have been attempting to calculate the force between them. I just wanted to double check my results with the community and hopefully get some advice as the graph looks as expected, but the numbers are very very large.

[image: force between two magnets]

---

This is the main equation i am using to calculate force. (as per Ravaud, R; Lemarquand, G; Babic, S; Lemarquand, V; Akyel, C (2010): https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5458080 ; further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets )

$$F(x)\simeq \left[\frac {B_0^2 A^2 \left( L^2+R^2 \right)} {\pi\mu_0L^2}\right] \left[{\frac 1 {x^2}} + {\frac 1 {(x+2L)^2}} - {\frac 2 {(x+L)^2}} \right]$$

where

```
B0 is the flux density very close to each pole, in [T, = 0.71]
A is the area of each pole, in m2, [A = 3.142]
L is the length of each magnet, in m, [L = 0.005]
R is the radius of each magnet, in m, and [R = 0.01]
x is the separation between the two magnets, in m  ranges from [x = 0.1, to x = 0.57]
```

Finally, i used the following equation to calculate the magnetic flux density (according to Chikazumi, Sōshin (1997)):https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization

$$B_0 \,=\, \frac{\mu_0}{2}M$$

such that $\mu_0 = 4\pi\times 10^-7$ and $M = mv$. V being the volume of the magnet ($0.126m^3$) and m being magntisation $M=(1/\mu_o)B_r$

at the maximum distance of 0.57m, the force produced by the two magnets is = 16.5148088143021N, at the minimum distance, i get a force = 15581.3960030775N.

I have managed to fix a few mistakes this morning, so the numbers are looking a bit more reasonable, but wanted to double check with the community if that's ok. I am just looking for advice on my line of thought, or whether I missed the mark entirely.

Many thanks 
Tony

Comment: I think this question would fit better into the physics or the engineering stackexchange.

Comment: Looks more like physics as opposed to math to me? Also, the tag description tells us that [tag:electromagnetism] should never be the only tag.

Comment: thanks.. i'll move it over there

Comment: Can you give a reference to where this equation is derived for curiosity's sake

Comment: Hi Nadide, i added a few links in a recient edit, but this is the paper Cylindrical Magnets and Coils: Fields, Forces, and Inductances; Ravaud et al. (2010): https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5458080 there is more information on a wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets

Comment: Can't read the paper, but the wiki link is helpful I don't see yet how exactly this equation is derived but makes a lot more of sense now and the image next to the equation also helps visualize it, thank you very much.

Comment: @nadide no problem at all. The wiki page offers a nice enough introduction on what im trying to apply, but not much depth on were the equations come from